# XBMC Kodi Subtitles Not Showing

Tags: python, xbmc, kodi

I am trying to get a subtitle track to play with a video, but my subtitles are not appearing. This is the srt file:

https://adbience-staging.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/podcast_srt_english_b9e728d9-7953-4ff6-b287-e150be3d4b45

My code  is as follows:

```
player  = ExamplePlayer()

subtitle_file='https://adbience-staging.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/podcast_srt_english_b9e728d9-7953-4ff6-b287-e150be3d4b45'

def downloadSubtitles(subtitlesUrl):
        global player

        while not player.isPlaying():
            xbmc.sleep(5) #wait until video is being played
        player.setSubtitles(subtitlesUrl)
        player.showSubtitles(True)
        xbmc.Player().setSubtitles(subtitlesUrl)

player.play(item=file, listitem=items)
downloadSubtitles(subtitle_file)
```

But the subtitles never show up in the layer. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe this helps you? https://github.com/xbmc/generator-kodi-addon/blob/master/generators/app/templates/resources/lib/subtitle.py#L131-L143

Comment: @Razze are you suggest the file has to be local first?

Comment: I would think so, but I'm not the expert in this field.